# Is the bubble sort algorithm more efficient for sorting and how to implement it?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I don't know which algorithm is more efficient for sorting, but I want to use Bubble sort and how to implement this algorithm.

Comment: More efficient than what, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not efficient at all. Its main advantage is that it is short to write, but that's all.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_sorts) for a comparison on comparison sorts.

If you still want to implement Bubble Sort, check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Implementation) for a description.

Comment: There is a case where bubblesort is optimal: if you started with a sorted array A, and changed all keys by a tiny amount to get an array A’, and need to sort A’. Depends on the array size and the size of the changes.

Comment: Good answer for including what benefit Bubble sort does have: quick to write, hard to get wrong.

Comment: @gnasher729 You are right, but even in that case I'd rather use an insertion sort.

Comment: @gnasher729: is that an intuition or a known fact ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good starting point is to look at a concrete sorting problem and then check the most voted solutions on LeetCode.

If you want to know how good bubble sort works on the problem you can just [filter the submitted solutions for "bubble sort"](https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-colors/solutions/?q=bubble+sort&orderBy=most_votes) and compare the runtime of it with the other (e.g. higher rated) solutions using other sort algorithms
(but: you need to register to be able to run solutions and compare their runtimes)

Comment: The votes on LeetCode should be considered with a strong critical mind. Better read some theory about sorting.